# Why does the shortcut for finding inverse of 2x2 matrices work?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

There is a short-cut for finding the inverse of 2x2 matrices

[image: Image of proof]

Can someone please explain why it works ? because I can't find any proof ?

Comment: Did you try multiplying the claimed result by $A$?

Comment: I know that it works, I want to know why it works

Comment: Well, it works because, it works. There are no hidden reasons here. It is just a simple calculation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. "why it works" isn't a very good question, especially if you swat away suggestions such as my first comment.

Comment: The formula can be easily derived with Gauss Jordan

Comment: Oh man, [mathmeeting.com](http://www.mathmeeting.com/), free homework help and solutions. Hm... just to let you know, our [site policies](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) are probably different than mathmeeting's.

Comment: I'm not asking for the answer to a homework question simply a reason why a short-cut I was taught works

Comment: Yes, I know. But since this seems to be your first question, I wanted to point you towards our help center. Note that your question may be downvoted and closed due to a lack of effort/context; this site tends to encourage questions that show thought has been put into them.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is an invertible $2 \times 2$ matrix, then it satisfies:

$$A A^{-1} = I$$

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$. Then you need to solve the augmented system:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
  a&b&1&0\\
  c&d&0&1\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

Now row-reduce this system until the left side becomes $I$. The right side will then give you the desired $A^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks gave me the best overview

Answer (score 3):

The r.h.s. is the adjugate matrix of $A$, i.e. the transpose of the matrix of cofactors of $A$, which is easy to calculate in the case of $2\times2$ matrices.

One proves, independently of the size of the matrix, that 
$$A\cdot\operatorname{adj}A=(\det A)\,I.$$
This formula is a rewriting of Laplace's formula, and is valid for matrices over any commutative ring.

Answer (score 0):

If an inverse for A exists, it is unique.

Simply multiply out the two matrices; the off-diagonal elements in the result are zero ($-ab+ab$, $cd-cd$).  The diagonal elements are both $ad-bc$.  Now, recall the determinant is simply $ad-bc$, so when you divide by that the result is the identity matrix.

There really isn't any more to prove here.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the classical adjoint matrix.

If we have $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$, then $A^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{\det(A)}*adj(A)$

Now the $adj(A)= \begin{bmatrix} (-1)^{1+1}d & (-1)^{1+2}c\\ (-1)^{2+1}b & (-1)^{2+2}a \end{bmatrix}^T=\begin{bmatrix} d & -c\\ -b & a \end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} d & -b\\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}$

Now $\det(A)$ is simply $ad-cb$, and so we have that $$A^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{ad-cb}\begin{bmatrix} d & -b\\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}$$

If you don't know the adjoint method, please look here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfhzwNkMNg4