# Understanding partial derivatives computation issued from an implicit change of variables.

Tags: analysis

Find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, if $xu-yv=0$ and $yu+xv=1$
Actually, I have an answer but I don't understand anything. Not because it is Chinese but transformations. Could you explain?[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: $v=\frac{x}{y}u$, substitute into the second equation and differentiate

Comment: "not because it is Chinese": I appreciate your humor...

Comment: Using the product rule, $(xu-yv)'=xdu+udx-ydv-vdy=0$. Do you get it now?

Comment: @Vasya this thing I understood

Comment: @Vasya but why in the second system the equation is like this

Comment: OK, $(1)'=0=(yu+xv)'$

Comment: @Vasya oh, I understand

Comment: @Vasya but by which variable do we differentiate? Or is it a formula without differentiating variable?

Comment: @kfcgenius: This is called implicit differentiation because we do not have a function that depends on some variables but an equation. Thus, we do not differentiate using a specific variable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first set of equations:

$$\begin{cases}xu-yv&=&0\\yu+xv&=&1\end{cases} \tag{0}$$

can be differentiated under the form:

$$\begin{cases}(udx+xdu)-(vdy+ydv)&=&0\\(u dy +y du)+(vdx+xdv)&=&0\end{cases},$$

giving the equivalent system:

$$\begin{cases}xdu-ydv&=&-udx+vdy\\ ydu+xdv&=&-vdx-udy\end{cases} $$

as in your book. Now, write it with matrices and vectors:

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}x&-y\\y&x \end{pmatrix}}_A\begin{pmatrix}du\\dv \end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}-u&v\\-v&-u\end{pmatrix}}_B \begin{pmatrix}dx\\dy \end{pmatrix}$$

from which you deduce that :

$$\begin{pmatrix}du\\dv \end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{A^{-1}B}_J \begin{pmatrix}dx\\dy \end{pmatrix}$$

It remains to compute matrix $J$:

$$J=\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\-y&x \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-u&v\\-v&-u\end{pmatrix}$$

$$J=\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}\begin{pmatrix}(-ux-vy)&(vx-uy)\\(uy-vx)&(-ux-vy)\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

**Remark:** We have used the classical [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564184/why-does-the-shortcut-for-finding-inverse-of-2x2-matrices-work) for the inverse of a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

$J$ is the **jacobian matrix** of the transformation $(x,y) \to (u,v)$, whose entries are precisely:

$$J=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$

It remains to identify the corresponding entries in (1) and (2).

**Edit : important remark:** My attention has been triggered by the fact that:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \ \ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

which are called "Cauchy-Riemann equations", classical for analytical ("smooth") complex functions.

Nothing surprizing because the initial relationships can be written plainly :

$$(x+iy)(u+iv)=i \ \iff \ u+iv=\dfrac{i}{x+iy}$$

finally giving

$$u+iv=\dfrac{i(x-iy)}{(x+iy)(x-iy)}=\dfrac{y+ix)}{x^2+y^2}$$

Otherwise said, identifying real and imaginary parts, we have explicit expressions:

$$u=\dfrac{y}{x^2+y^2}, \ \ \ v=\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2},\tag{3}$$

from which the partial derivatives are easily obtained...

(transformation (3) is a parent of the classical "inversion" transform)

Comment: Do you mean 2x2 matrice?

Comment: And if both equations in system are both equals to 0, can I just unite them in one equation?

Comment: You could treat a single system by using complex numbers, but, as you can see, with the method I propose you, you reach the result.

Comment: How we got $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ in jacobian?

Comment: Because the formula for the inverse of a matrix $A$ begins by $\frac{1}{\det(A)}$

Comment: I understand, thank you

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your initial title "solve this task".